# How do you show the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^∞ 2^n\tan(1/n!)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do you show the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^∞ 2^n\tan(1/n!)$?

Does one use the ratio test? If so, how?

Comment: Hint: Show that $0\le\tan x\le 2x$ for $0\le x\le \pi/4$.

Comment: Do you know the inequality $\sin(x) \leq x$?

Comment: You should be able to "use the ratio test", perhaps by applying l'Hopital's rule.  It would be worthwhile to share an attempt at this, or to explain the *context* of the problem with some specifics.

Answer (score 3):

When $n\to\infty$, $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n!}\to 0$, so $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \displaystyle\frac{\tan\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{n!}\right)}{1/n!}=1$.

Thus, the series has the same character as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$, where $a_n=\displaystyle\frac{2^n}{n!}$.

Applying the ratio test, we reach $$\displaystyle\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\displaystyle\frac{2}{n+1}\to 0$$

Then we conclude that the sum of $a_n$ converges and our original series does too.

Answer (score 0):

Another point of view is [image]$$0\le \tan (\frac 1{n!})\le 2\times \frac 1{n!} $$
so $$0\le\ \sum_{n=1}^∞ 2^n\tan(\frac 1{n!})
 \le \sum_{n=1}^∞ 2^n \times 2*(\frac 1{n!})
\\0\le\ \sum_{n=1}^∞ 2^n\tan(\frac 1{n!})\le 2\sum_{n=1}^∞  (\frac {2^n}{n!})\\\
0\le\ \sum_{n=1}^∞ 2^n\tan(\frac 1{n!})\le 2(e^2-1)$$

Remark : $$e^x=\frac 1{0!}+\frac x{1!}+\frac {x^2}{2!}+\frac {x^3}{3!}+\cdots $$